# Mapping results of the repositories to the AGGREGATION ENTITY in DOMAIN layer

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, dapper, cqrs, clean-architecture

I'm working in a project with .NET core 3 and C# as language. 
I'm trying to use Clean Architecture approach, CQRS and Repository Patterns. I chose DAPPER as ORM.

I have 3 layers:

- DOMAIN : with my entities, aggregation entities, value object;
- APPLICATION : here I'm implementing the logic with QUERIES and COMMAND (CQRS) and interface (for example repositories) that I'll implement in PERSISTENCE layer;
- PERSISTENCE : with DAPPER, this layer share the same entities of the DOMAIN.

I have doubt about how to create aggregation entity. For example:

Class `Person` is an aggregation and a `Person` can have 1 to N`Photo`

```
public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
            Photos = new HashSet<PersonHasPhotos>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set;}

        public ICollection<PersonHasPhotos> Photos  { get;  set; }

    }
```

Class `Photo` is normal entity

```
public class Photo
    {
        public Photo()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set;}
        public string Description { get; set;}
        public byte[] Photo { get; set;}


    }
```

Class `PersonHasPhotos` that specify where (the position in the screen) the Person wants to see the photo in his HOME PAGE

```
public class PersonHasPhotos
    {
        public PersonHasPhotos()
        {
        }

        public int PersonId { get; set;}
        public int PhotoId { get; set;}
        public string PositionOnTheScreen { get; set;}

        public Photo Photo { get; set;}
        public Person Person { get; set;}


    }
```

In my APPLICATION layer I defined one REPOSITORY for each entity. Each repository has simple job specific for the entity (only simple CRUD, without JOIN). I chose this because I'll use repositories in APPLICATION layer and there I can put logic and also manage transactions.

I have `IPersonRepository`, `IPhotoRepository` and `IPersonHasPhotoRepository`.

```
public interface IPersonHasPhotosRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<PersonHasPhotos> GetForPerson(int PersonId);

    }

public interface IPhotosRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Photos> Get(int PersonId);

    }

public interface IPersonRepository
    {
        Person Get(int PersonId);

    }
```

In my APPLICATION layer I have a QUERY named `GetPerson(int id)`. In the HANDLER of this query I call these repositories.

In my PERSISTENCE layer with DAPPER I can map the results of the query directly to my entity. 
The domain entities are shared in all layers and I don't want to put logic in PERSISTENCE layer to explain how to create aggregation entity.

The problem is that these repositories give to me 3 different objects (`Person`, `List<PersonHasPhoto>`, `List<Photo>`) but I would like to merge them in only one object PERSON with its properties enhanced with the others objects.

What should I do? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you think the person entity look like with enhanced properties?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya like the first entity Person that I wrote in my post but in this way I can navigate through the properties and also put specific logic. For example I can put a method in Person that extract a particular photo from the collection of the photo.

Comment: Person entry have Photos collection populated? Can you run linq on it to select specific item and then get Photo property of it? Currently how are you populating the person object using Dapper?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya with Dapper I defined 3 repositories for the 3 entity. When I get Person with Dapper I receive the entity Person with all the others properties empty because I want that each repository work on a single specific table without knowing about how the table are joined. If you read my post you will see that my problem isn't how to read from a collection but where I should aggregate these 3 object in one and how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options

- live with the fact that those three repositories return different entities (instances) and "link" and compare them based on their IDs
- go for "Unit of work" pattern and have one repository returning always all three entities combined